# UIImageView position changes after a button setBackgroundImage is called in iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

In the default view of my `iOS` Window I have two elements. One is a `UIImageView` and the other is a `UIButton`.

When the app launches I move the `UIImageView` through `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` by animating the self.basebar.center property. It does this and remains in the set position which is basically y - 60pt.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
 delay:0.1
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
 animations:^{
 self.basebar.center  = CGPointMake(self.basebar.center.x,  self.basebar.center.y + 60.f);
 }
 completion:nil ];
```

The `UIButton` in the same view as the `myUIViewImage`.

When I click the `UIButton` the action does what it is supposed to and just sets a different background image to the button... But the self.basebar.center returns back to the originating position?

Any ideas why this is being caused - is the who view being redrawn and the original self.basebar.center

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout... The layout was reverting to original layout when the button was being clicked..